# Unix remove old files based on date from file name

Tags: unix

I have filenames in a directory like:

```
ACCT_GA12345_2015-01-10.xml
ACCT_GA12345_2015-01-09.xml
ACCT_GDC789g_2015-01-09.xml
ACCT_GDC567g_2015-01-09.xml
ACCT_GDC567g_2015-01-08.xml
ACCT_GCC7894_2015-01-01.xml
ACCT_GCC7894_2015-01-02.xml
ACCT_GAC7884_2015-02-01.xml
ACCT_GAC7884_2015-01-01.xml
```

I want to have only the latest file in the folder. The latest file can be found using only the file name (NOT the date stamp). For example ACCT 12345 has files from 1/10 & 1/09. I need to delete 1/09 file and have only 1/10 file, for ACCT 789g there is only one file so I have to have that file, and ACCT 567g the latest file is 1/09 so I have to remove 1/08 and have 1/09. So the combination for latest file should be ACCT & Max date for that ACCT.

I would need the final list of files as:

```
ACCT_GA12345_2015-01-10.xml
ACCT_GDC789g_2015-01-09.xml
ACCT_GDC567g_2015-01-09.xml
ACCT_GCC7894_2015-01-02.xml
ACCT_GAC7884_2015-02-01.xml
```

Can someone help me with this command in unix? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this.... to test start with ls command, when you get what you want to delete, then do rm.

```
ls ACCT_{GDC,GA1}*-{09,10}.xml
```

this will list any GDC or GA1 files that end in 09 or 10. You can play with combinations and different values until you have the right set of files showing that you want deleted. once you to just change ls to rm and you should be golden.

With some more info I could help you out. To test this out I did:

```
touch ACCT_{GDC,GA1}_{01..10}_{05..10}.xml
```

this will make 56 different dummy files with different combinations. Make a directory, run this command, and get your hands dirty. That is the best way to learn linux cli. Also 65% of commands you need, you will learn, understand, use then never use again...so learn how to teach yourself how to use man pages and setup a spot to play around in.

Comment: I edited the question with more information. In your command we are looking for files ending with 09 or 10. But that will not be the case always.

Comment: ACCT_(\D{1,3}\d{1,5}[g]{0,1})_[\d]{4}-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2}).xml

This is a regex string that will break up your filenames into $1 $2 $3 where $1 is GAC7884 or whatever, $2 is month $3 is day.

Look into using Regex in a shell script file. You can google this. I would love to write it all for you, but I have my own programming to do. I will answer and questions you have along the way though. Essentially you want to use this regex on each filename, build up a list of everything except the most recent, then delete. don't delete until your 100% sure though, or unless you have back up. Good luck!